# Problems when performing a query set of those leagues that have events filtered by a date timestamps

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

We have two models where we need to make a filter of those leagues that have games on a given date, this date is a timestamp example =: 1698292800 all this works fine, the problem is that when we get the results of this filter it brings events from other dates including the one that was filtered.

## Models

> FootballLeague model contains all soccer leagues.

```
class FootballLeague(UUIDModel, TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=255, db_index=True)
    country_name = models.CharField(
        _("Country"), max_length=255, db_index=True, null=True, blank=True
    )
    country_id = models.IntegerField(_("Country ID"), null=True, blank=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Football League")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Football Leagues")
        ordering = ["name"]
```

> EventsFootball model contains all games related to a league.

```
class EventsFootball(UUIDModel):
    event_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_time = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    home_score_current = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    home_score_part_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    home_score_part_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
   
    home_images = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    away_score_current = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    away_score_part_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    away_score_part_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    info_notice = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    away_images = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    league = models.ForeignKey(
        FootballLeague, related_name="events", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.league.name} - {self.round}"
```

> The relationship or query performed so far where the games of the filtered date are brought here everything goes well when performing a print of filtered_events brings those games that are on that date.

```
events = EventsFootball.objects.filter(
            start_time__gte=timestamp_inicio, start_time__lte=timestamp_fin
        ).values_list("event_id", flat=True)
```

> Here the problem to obtain the result brings the leagues but with events that are not in the first first filter

```
queryset = FootballLeague.objects.filter(
            events__event_id__in=eventos_filtrados,
        )
```

> Example of the result where only in events should bring such event with date 2023-10-27

```
{
    "links": {
        "next": null,
        "previous": null
    },
    "count": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "short_name": "UEFA Nations League Femenina",
            "name": "Europa: UEFA Nations League Femenina - Liga A",
            "tournament_stage_id": "rgU5w0eQ",
            "tournament_id": null,
            "tournament_image": "https://www.flashscore.com/res/image/data/Q7GMJzmd-SWnXZ8VO.png",
            "tournament_season_id": "jZ4CaGVm",
            "group_id": null,
            "template_id": "6_GWpMLXB0",
            "events": [
                {
                    "start_time": "2023-10-28 12:30:00",
                    "favorite": false,
                    "event_id": "YuP7vwa9",
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "2023-10-30 13:00:00",
                    "favorite": false,
                    "event_id": "0hAjFMVc",
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "2023-10-17 14:30:00",
                    "favorite": false,
                    "event_id": "2eg8JyNq",
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "2023-10-12 14:45:00",
                    "favorite": false,
                    "event_id": "0W2fCabJ",
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "2023-10-21 14:45:00",
                    "favorite": false,
                    "event_id": "A3e82qnh",
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "2023-10-27 11:45:00",
                    "favorite": false,
                    "event_id": "pvBbUhy2",
                }
            ],
            "country": {
                "flag": "/media/livescores/upload/country_flag_6.png",
                "code": "Europa"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you filter the FootballLeague objects based on the filtered events, Django returns the leagues that have any event within the specified timestamp range. But, once you get a specific FootballLeague object, it will return all events connected to that object, disregarding the previous filter.

I am guessing you are using this query in a View. For this to work you can specify the events returned through the Serializer.

```py
class FootballLeagueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    events = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = FootballLeague
        fields = ('name', 'events', ...)

    def get_events(self, obj):
        # Using the filtered event ids provided in the context
        filtered_event_ids = self.context.get('filtered_event_ids', [])
        return EventFootballSerializer(obj.events.filter(event_id__in=filtered_event_ids), many=True).data
```

In the View you can do the following.

```py
filtered_event_ids = EventsFootball.objects.filter(
    start_time__gte=timestamp_inicio, start_time__lte=timestamp_fin
).values_list('event_id', flat=True)

leagues = FootballLeague.objects.filter(events__event_id__in=filtered_event_ids)

serializer = FootballLeagueSerializer(leagues, many=True, context={'filtered_event_ids': filtered_event_ids})
data = serializer.data
```